# Performing a jquery operation on all drop down lists on the page

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

So I have all my drop down lists marked with `class="ddl"`

I used this, wanting to add "Select" as a first element for ALL the drop down lists on the page - there are several drop down lists.

```
 $(".ddl option").eq(0).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

But it only works on the first drop down list...Do I need to loop through each one?

html

```
<select class="ddl" id="ddl-id1" name="ddl-name1">
<option value="6">option 1 text</option>
<option value="11">option 2 text</option>
<option value="19">option 3 text</option>
<!-- etc -->
</select>     


<select class="ddl" id="ddl-id2" name="ddl-name2">
<option value="7">some text</option>
<option value="10">some other text</option>
<option value="24">more text</option>
<!-- etc -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$(".ddl option:first-child").before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

[Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/h4eYS/).

EDIT:

If one of the dropdowns is empty, you can use this approach

```
$(".ddl").prepend($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

[Here it is in action with an empty dropdown](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/h4eYS/2/)

Comment: I need it to work for ALL the drop down lists on the page. Not just the first one.

Comment: Considering you have class of .ddl on all of them, this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I will update the question with HTML.

Comment: Check again :-) I left out a bit of the selector.

Comment: No problem, please mark as answered when you get the chance, thanks!

Comment: quick question - what if one of the lists happens to be empty....this won't work on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `eq(0)` is causing your set of elements to only contain the first element; that is, the first option on the first dropdown list.

Try

```
$(".ddl option:first").before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the rest of the HTML markup, but if you are trying to loop through all elements with a specific class, you likely would have to use `.each()` with a callback to do the before <option> insertion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep intact the ability to choose where you place the new `<option>` you can iterate through each of the `<select>`'s with `.each()`:

```
$(".ddl").each(function (index, value) {
    $(this).children('option').eq(0).before($("<option></option>").val("").text("Select"));
});
```

This leave you the ability to add the new `<option>` at whatever place you want (using `.eq(2)` will add the new element before the third current `<option>`).

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7rwR7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/ZKeGr/)

```
$('<option>Select one</option>').prependTo('.ddl');
```

If you want to display the `Select one` as default value you can add a `selected='selected'`